# printf em Java - Para que serve o %3d?

Tags: java, printf

Estou vendo um exercícios de arrays em java, mas não consigo entender pra quê serve o `%3d`, se é um `int`.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    System.out.printf("a[%d] = %3d   b[%d] = %3d\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `%d` é utilizado para formatar variáveis inteiras, basicamente pode ser usado da seguinte forma:

- `%d` - formata uma variável inteira com quantos dígitos existirem;
- `%4d` - formata uma variável inteira com quantos dígitos existirem, mas se a variável tiver uma quantidade menor do que 4 dígitos, preenche os faltantes com espaço em branco à esquerda;
- `%04d` - formata uma variável inteira com quantos dígitos existirem, mas se a variável tiver uma quantidade menor do que 4 dígitos, preenche os faltantes com zeros à esquerda.

Exemplos:

- `%d` aplicado a 1234 ficaria 1234;
- `%4d` aplicado a 1234 ficaria 1234, mas aplicado a 123 ficaria _123 (onde _ é um espaço em branco);
- `%04d` aplicado a 123 ficar 0123.

Veja um exemplo: http://ideone.com/0JxzzH

Comment: O %d eu entendi, mas o '3', ele é usado para dar um espaço em branco então?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Atualizei a minha resposta com um link.

Comment: O 3 é usado pra definir quantos espaços em brancos serão dados em um inteiro com uma quantidade menor do que 3 dígitos.

Comment: Simmm, menor que %3d

Answer (score 6):

A explicação do `%3d` pode ser dividida conforme abaixo:

- `%` imprima uma variável aqui,
- `3` use ao menos 3 caracteres para exibir, preenchendo com espaços se necessário,
- `d` a variável é do tipo `int`.

Veja um exemplo demonstrativo no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/rFVfWs).

Fonte: [What does “%3d” mean in a printf statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806120/1964435)